# Plot a horizontal line reference in combination with boxplot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

I want to add a horizontal line i.e. a 'reference' in `boxplot`. I tried following code, but it doesn't work as expected.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"Prior": initial_FOPR,
                "DSI": pca_FOPR,
                "DSI.ESMDA": ksvd_FOPR,
                "DSI.ESMDA.LOC": dct_FOPR,"ES-MDA": Basic_FOPR,})
df.boxplot(grid=False, rot=45, fontsize=15)
plt.hlines(reference,xmin=min(reference),xmax=max(reference),'r')
```

The desired result:
[image: expected result]

Comment: Is `reference` an array? I think that line should be something like `plt.hlines(reference, xmin=min(your x axes), xmax=max(your x axes))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you seem to want to draw a line spanning the whole width of the axes, it would be simpler to use [`plt.axhline()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axhline.html?highlight=axhline#matplotlib.pyplot.axhline), which was meant for this precise use.

Then your code would simply be:

```
df.boxplot(grid=False, rot=45, fontsize=15)
plt.axhline(reference, c='r')
```

Answer (score 4):

`xmin` and `xmax` are meant to be the leftmost and rightmost of your x-axis. As your x-axis is just a list of labels, `matplotlib` internally uses numbers 0, 1, 2, ...  `plt.xlim()` is an easy way to fetch these limits. To have dashed lines, use '--' as the linestyle.

The first parameter to `hlines`, which is called `reference` in this example, is the y-position where to draw the horizontal line. If `reference` is an array, multiple horizontal lines can be drawn at once.

`plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()` can help to better fit the image by automatically choosing a rotation for the x-labels.

Here is an example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

N = 50
df = pd.DataFrame({"Prior": np.random.geometric(0.5, N) * 2 + 10,
                   "DSI": np.random.geometric(0.1, N) * 3 + 20,
                   "DSI.ESMDA": np.random.geometric(0.2, N) + 40,
                   "DSI.ESMDA.LOC": np.random.geometric(0.2, N) * 4 + 30,
                   "ES-MDA": np.random.geometric(0.7, N) * 2.5 + 60})
df.boxplot(grid=False, rot=18, fontsize=15)
reference = [20, 50, 75]
left, right = plt.xlim()
plt.hlines(reference, xmin=left, xmax=right, color='r', linestyles='--')
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.20)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Additional notes:

- `plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.20)` provides more space so the tick labels don't get cut off by the image bottom. A rotation of about 20° makes the plot somewhat more compact.
- A `linestyle=':'` (dotted instead of dashed) could be nicer for this graph.
- As remarked by @Diziet Asahi, `plt.axhline` is an alternative to draw a horizontal line. Remark that `axhline` only accepts one number, not a list, as first parameter.